# Gross National Income for Personal Income?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, statistics

is there such a thing as the measure that amounts to roughly the aggregate of personal income for a country (say: all salaries combined) and an aggregate of corporate income. But as separate figures, in dollars.

(Specifically, I am interested in Canada.)

Comment: Since someone owns the corporations the line between corporate and personal income is quite blurred. Do you mean labor income?

Comment: I mean whatever can be claimed as taxable personal income (salary, investments, etc.). An aggregate of that for all individuals in a country.